# Discrete wavelet transform to detect saturation point of start and end

Tags: wavelet, transform

can someone help me to detect the saturation point using wavelet transform which contain 2 waveform signal. I don't know the correct step to detect the saturation point of distorted waveform and I just use wavelet toolbox to detect. the first image is what I'm trying to do and another below is example answer that I should follow.

My work

[image]

Example

[image]